# ¿como agregar campos a un array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, array

Como realizo en manera dinámica con Javascript la siguiente funcionalidad:

tengo 3 campos con su respectivo id:

- id_municipio
- area_en_el_parque
- proporcion

Al momento de salida quiero que estos 3 campos de manera dinámica me retornen un Array, por ejemplo:

```
var array = [
    {"id_municipio":"4","area_en_el_parque ":19,"Proporción":"2"},
    {"id_municipio":"87","area_en_el_parque ":30,"Proporción":"2"},
    {"id_municipio":"175","area_en_el_parque ":34,"Proporción":"20"}
]
```

Select de Municipio:

```
<select class="form-control" required="required" id="id_municipios" name="id_municipios">
    <option value="3">Ejemplo1</option>
    <option value="2">Ejemplo2</option>
    <option value="1">Ejemplo3</option>
</select>
```

Campo area_en_el_parque

```
<input class="form-control" required="required" id="area_en_el_parque " name="area_en_el_parque " type="number">
```

Campo proporcion

```
<input class="form-control" required="required" id="proporcion" name="proporcion" type="number">
```

Comment: No queda claro en que momento quieres que se ejecute la funcionalidad a que te refieres cuando dices "Al momento de salida" ? . Quieres que se ejecute cuando cambias tu select ? , Cuando se termine de cargar la pagina ?.  Los datos están  en una base de datos ?.

Answer (score 0):

La función que tiene javascript para agregar datos a un array es array.push()

Si entiendo que quieres hacer una variable en javascript que se vaya llenando con los datos del formulario, pues creo que este ejemplo podría servirte.

```
<script>
    var array = [];

    function agrego_array() {
        var id_mun = document.getElementById("id_municipios");
        var id_are = document.getElementById("area_en_el_parque");
        var id_pro = document.getElementById("proporcion");

        array.push({
            id_municipios: id_mun.value,
            area_en_el_parque: id_are.value,
            proporcion: id_pro.value,
        });
        console.log(array);
    }

</script>
```

Para usar la función javascript agrego_array() , hice un botón el cual lo ejecuta.  En tu caso deberías usar esa función en el lugar que te haga falta.

```
<select class="form-control" required="required" id="id_municipios" name="id_municipios">
    <option value="3">Ejemplo1</option>
    <option value="2">Ejemplo2</option>
    <option value="1">Ejemplo3</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" required="required" id="area_en_el_parque" name="area_en_el_parque " type="number" >
<input class="form-control" required="required" id="proporcion" name="proporcion" type="number" >

<input type="button" onclick="agrego_array()" value="Agregar en Array">
```

La función muestra con console.log() el array que se va conformando el cual puedes ver en el console del browser.

Espero te sea de utilidad